# What is the best way in Angular client to animate data changes coming from SignalR

Tags: angular, signalr

In nutshell: I have a backend that fires signals to a hub periodically.
My angular client updates the data on the UI based on these signals.

What is the best way to animate these model data changes?

**Update:**

I didn't describe the data because I have a lot of different models visualized on a lot of child components.
In my "real-time app" I would like to for example animate the background of each changed property of the model when a corresponding signal happens.

I wasn't able to use browser animations because it worked only if the data change happened on the same page, not from the signal.

Another thing which I would like to avoid is to use ViewChilds to get elements from DOM in .ts files and make animation on them directly.

My general question was what's the best practice with data update animations and signalR

Comment: Please be more specific, describe the data, desired general behavior, and visualization

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jehugaleahsa/825518ee860b84d3a041c17ccf095f61) you can find an example of how to integrate SignalR into an Angular app. As many other real time backend, you can use a service as a data communication interface, you can inject this service dependency in multiple child components and bind data values to view templates using rxjs Observable variables and async calls (subscribe to Observable, Subjects, async pipe, etc).